# Big O notation sum rule

Tags: big-o

I understand that when adding functions, the behaviour is dominated by the highest power. But I have trouble understanding the proof. Could anyone help me step by step in explaining the proof behind

```
T1(n) + T2(n) => O(max (f(n), g(n)))
```

Thank you very much

Comment: I believe you would get better answers on the [math.se] site than here

Answer (score 2):

The notation f(n) = O(g(n)) is really shorthand for:

> There exists N > 0 and c > 0 such that for all n > N, f(n) ≤ c g(n).

The equals sign in f(n) = O(g(n)) is really an abuse of notation; it really means f∈O(g), though no one actually writes that. So, we have the obvious

> n = O(n),
>
> 1000 n = O(n),

and even

> 1000 n = O(n²).

Note that this does not mean O(n) = O(n²), thinking of O(n) and O(n²) as sets of functions; unlike equality, expressions using O-notation are not reflexive. Any O(n) function is O(n²), but not the reverse.

So, as an example, we'll show that

> n³ + 1000 n² + 10000 = O(n³).
>
> Let N be the largest coefficient: N = 10000. Then, for n > N,
>
> n³ + 1000 n² + 10000 <  n³ + N n² + N < n³ + n n² + n < n³ + n³ + n³ = 3 n³.

Polynomials are dominated by the highest-degree term. And now the solution to your problem is clear.

> If T₁(n) = O(f(n)), then there is a N₁ and a c₁ such that for all n > N₁, T₁(n) ≤ c₁ f(n).
>
> If T₂(n) = O(g(n)), then there is a N₂ and a c₂ such that for all n > N₂, T₂(n) ≤ c₂ g(n).
>
> Let c = max(c₁, c₂) and N = max(N₁, N₂). Then, for n > N,
>
> T₁(n) + T₂(n) ≤ c₁ f(n) + c₂ g(n)
>
> ≤ c f(n) + c g(n) = c (f(n) + g(n))
>
> ≤ c ⋅ (2 max(f(n), g(n))) = 2c max(f(n), g(n)).

It helps if you've done ε-δ proofs in calculus.